# Issue with Red Carpet gem recognizing markdown text from bootsy gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, redcarpet

I am new to Ruby on rails and am currently working on a project that is similar to stack overflow in the sense that users will be able to ask questions and submit answers in regard to coding.

I have recently installed the bootsy gem to make a nice user interface that will allow users to submit photos along with their text. However, since I have installed this gem, my red carpet gem has ceased to recognize the formatting for inline code within the bootsy_area.

This is the code in the new.html.haml/edit.html.haml page for a question:

```
      = f.bootsy_area :content, editor_options: {color: false, font_styles: false, link: false}, class: "form-control", id: "question_content"
```

This is the code displaying on the show page for a question:

```
  .question-content
    = markdown(@question.content)
```

This is the code in my application_helper.rb file that uses red carpet:

```
def markdown(text)
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, autolink: true).render(text).html_safe
end
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix inline code showing up in the view? Thank you!